# Understanding IOC container - beans.xml

Tags: java, spring, ioc-container

Below syntax in `beans.xml`,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation=" http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="springQuizMaster" class="com.vaannila.SpringQuizMaster"></bean>
    <bean id="strutsQuizMaster" class="com.vaannila.StrutsQuizMaster"></bean>
    <bean id="quizMasterService1" class="com.vaannila.QuizMasterService1">
        <property name="quizMaster">
        <ref local="springQuizMaster"/>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="quizMasterService2" class="com.vaannila.QuizMasterService2">
        <property name="quizMaster">
        <ref local="springQuizMaster"/>
        </property>
    </bean>    
</beans>
```

---

tells *Spring IOC container* that,

1)

```
<bean id="springQuizMaster" class="com.vaannila.SpringQuizMaster"></bean>
<bean id="strutsQuizMaster" class="com.vaannila.StrutsQuizMaster"></bean>
```

only instances of class `springQuizMaster` & class `strutsQuizMaster`  need to be instantiated, as dependencies, if required, in future.

Another advantage is, `beans.xml` can be updated with new dependencies in runtime, without restarting my Spring application, by adding more dependencies, something like `<bean id="xyzQuizMaster" class="com.vaannila.XYZQuizMaster"></bean>`.

2)

```
<bean id="quizMasterService1" class="com.vaannila.QuizMasterService1">
    <property name="quizMaster">
    <ref local="springQuizMaster"/>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="quizMasterService2" class="com.vaannila.QuizMasterService2">
    <property name="quizMaster">
    <ref local="springQuizMaster"/>
    </property>
</bean>
```

tells IOC container to maintain below [map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array) of dependencies:

```
class `QuizMasterService1` => array(class `SpringQuizMaster`,)
class `QuizMasterService2` => array(class `SpringQuizMaster`,)
```

**After** instantiating `QuizMasterService1`(say) in runtime, from java code, corresponding dependencies given in *array* will get instantiated by IOC container, right away.

---

Is this the right understanding about IOC container?

Comment: No... Your runtime modifications to `beans.xml` aren't detected upon restarting your application. Also creating instances yourself will not get any dependencies injected you will have to use the instances created by Spring.

Comment: @M.Deinum  aren't detected until restarting your application?

Comment: You have to restart your application for spring to load the modified beans.xml. You cannot simply change the wiring and expect at runtime (read live) adapt to the modified configuration. The configuration is static and changes aren't read.

Comment: @M.Deinum  When you say, *you will have to use the instances created by Spring*, Do you mean, Spring container creates two instances of `SpringQuizMaster` **after** application instantiates `QuizMasterService1` & `QuizMasterService1`, in runtime?

Comment: @M.Deinum If I need to restart my spring application for spring to load the modified `beans.xml`, then I wrote similar [IOC container](https://github.com/shamhub/Computing/tree/master/code_Sedgewick/design2Code/PriorityQueue) that maintains map of dependencies and finds the dependencies in run time using *service location pattern*, but not DI.

Comment: If you even restart your application the configuration doesn't reflect it, and everything goes to Restitutio in integrum.

Comment: So it isn't an IOC container but merely a service location pattern and no it will create 1 instance of the `SpringQuizmaster` as beans are by default singleton in Spring.

Comment: @M.Deinum if it is just a service locator pattern, then that means dependencies are already available to locate. Where are the dependencies coming from? Are they not maintained by config.c?

Comment: @M.Deinum Same  instance of SpringQuizMaster to both QuizMasterService1 and QuizMasterService2?

Comment: I was referring to your own "ioc container" not Spring. Spring beans are by default singleton, so a single instance will be shared.

Comment: @M.Deinum Apart from implementing service locator pattern, why C code is not an IOC container? Config.c maintains array of dependencies before user locates the service based on given input. Isn’t it?